# SQL: Select A when in A and not B or select B when in A and B

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL is not my strong point and I am struggling to find a solution to this issue. I am trying to figure out how I can get a result set based on the following logic. Select record A when A is not in B OR select B if the record appears in B and A. I tried the following union which returns me all the records that match from the current day in the two tables but I cannot figure out how to pull the data I need from the two tables.

```
SELECT 'a',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM PurchaseOrderLine 
WHERE PurchaseOrderLine.dRequiredDate  = convert(date, getdate())
UNION 
SELECT 'b',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM GoodsIn
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderLine 
    ON PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId = GoodsIn.iPurchaseOrderLineId
WHERE GoodsIn.dDateDelivered =  getdate())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a left outer join, and use a ISNULL or CASE statement in the select to return the required values.

I'll demonstrate:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN b.iPurchaseOrderLineId IS NOT NULL THEN 'b' ELSE 'a' END AS [Source],
    a.iPurchaseOrderLineId,
    ISNULL(b.sProductDescription, a.sProductDescription) AS [sProductDescription]
FROM PurchaseOrderLine AS a
    LEFT JOIN GoodsIn AS b ON a.iPurchaseOrderLineId = b.iPurchaseOrderLineId
                           AND b.dDateDelivered = GETDATE()
WHERE b.iPurchaseOrderLineId IS NOT NULL 
      OR a.dRequiredDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm looking at it it seems to be putting duplicate results in. I tried adding a distinct but then certain results stopped appearing

Comment: I've added the DISTINCT, and editted the WHERE clause at the bottom, as I assume the dRequiredDate condition on A should only apply where there is no B! See if that works??

Comment: Ah I have just realised that I did have some entries in more than once which is actually correct.

Comment: If you edit to remove the distinct then the answer provided will be correct as there may be more than one instance of the iPurchaseOrderLineId.

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will help You: Just an example similar to you.

```
create table A(id int  , name char(12))
go

create table B(id int  , name char(12))
go

insert into A values (1,'ABC'),(3,'WXY')
insert into B values (1,'ABC'),(2,'AAA')


SELECT a.id,a.name FROM A EXCEPT SELECT * FROM B
UNION  
SELECT a.id,a.name FROM A inner join b on a.id=b.id and a.name=b.name
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I like your use of the Except keyword.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, assuming GoodsIn=B, you may try something in this fashion.

```
SELECT 'a',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM PurchaseOrderLine 
LEFT JOIN GoodsIn
    ON PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId = GoodsIn.iPurchaseOrderLineId
WHERE PurchaseOrderLine.dRequiredDate  = convert(date, getdate())
AND GoodsIn.iPurchaseOrderLineId IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT 'b',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM GoodsIn
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderLine 
    ON PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId = GoodsIn.iPurchaseOrderLineId
WHERE GoodsIn.dDateDelivered =  getdate());
```

You could also try literally as you described (assuming sProductDescription is in PurchaseOrderLine):

"Select record A when A is not in B"

```
SELECT 'a',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM PurchaseOrderLine 
WHERE iPurchaseOrderLineId NOT IN(SELECT iPurchaseOrderLineId FROM GoodsIn)
```

or in this way:

```
SELECT 'a',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM PurchaseOrderLine 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM GoodsIn 
    WHERE GoodsIn.iPurchaseOrderLineId=PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId)
```

or using EXCEPT:

```
SELECT 'a',PurchaseOrderLine.iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM PurchaseOrderLine 
EXCEPT 
SELECT 'a', iPurchaseOrderLineId, sProductDescription 
FROM GoodsIn;
```

Just hints, tailor them to your needs.